# Java ArrayList Multi-Threading NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I've created a Glassfish 4.0 server in Java and I'm getting a strange error on my `ArrayList<>`. Here is my `init()` code:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    init();
}

private void init() {
    sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(sessions){
                while(sessions.size() == 0){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("No sessions available: " + sessions);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }).start();
}
```

Essentially, when the server starts up the sessions `ArrayList` is instantiated, and a new Thread starts looping waiting for a WebSocket connection to occur. Here is the code for a WebSocket connection:

```
@OnOpen
public void open(Session session) {
    System.out.println("CONNECTED: " + session.getId());
    synchronized(sessions){
        sessions.add(session);
    }
}
```

So, the thread with the while loop should print out "No sessions available: []" until the open(...) method is called. However, whenever the code in the open method gets to `synchronized(sessions) {...}`, it says that sessions is null. This doesn't make sense considering that this method is NEVER called before the `init()` method that creates the sessions `ArrayList`.

So, what I did before was add in this code: `if(sessions == null) sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();` and then the synchronized code would run. This would work, and the session would be added, but it wouldn't appear in the second thread. The second thread would still be looping and printing out that there are no sessions available. What am I missing?

Stacktrace:

> 2016-02-18T15:13:13.601-0500|Severe: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at BotManager.open(BotManager.java:134)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.callMethod(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:431)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.onOpen(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:468)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.tyrus.core.EndpointWrapper.onConnect(EndpointWrapper.java:446)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusEndpoint.onConnect(TyrusEndpoint.java:146)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.tyrus.websockets.DefaultWebSocket.onConnect(DefaultWebSocket.java:122)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.init(TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:777)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: How is `sessions` defined?

Comment: Global variable ArrayList<Session> sessions;

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace of your `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @ScottyPippen you should show the whole class including declaration of the session member

Comment: @wero its a private global variable: private ArrayList<Session> sessions;

Comment: Is your `BotManager` an Endpoint and a ServletContextListener?

Comment: Which line of code is at line 134 in BotManager (method open())?

Comment: You have a deadlock issue with your synchronization - your runnable locks the list until the size is greater than 0, and you can't add to the list until it is unlocked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your have a class which acts as `ServletContextListener` and a websocket `EndPoint`.

The container creates an instance which acts as `ServletContextListener` at application startup and creates `Endpoint` instances whenever a client connects.

Now each of these instances has an own `sessions` field and in the Endpoint it is still null when you access it (it is only initialized in the ServletContextListener instance).

Solution: make the `sessions` field static (and then resolve the deadlock issue - see comment of Andrew Williamson) - for instance simply use a synchronized list.

Comment: Done! This is the correct solution! Thanks, I never would have guessed that there were multiple underlying instances of the same variables :)

Answer (score 0):

> that this method is NEVER called before the init()

Possibly `init()` truly runs before `open()` , but the state change (list initialization) is not necessarily visible on an other thread where `open()` runs. The sessions list initalization is not in any synchronized block, therefore it may be invisible for other threads. You have the following options:

- create the `ArrayList` instance in the class constructor (or at the field definition)
- always syncronize on `this` (and not on `sessions`) when you access or create the session list (`this` will never be null)

Comment: synchronized(this){ sessions = new ArrayList<Session>(); } is that what you're proposing in the init() method?

Comment: yes. And replace every existing  syncronized(sessions) to syncronized(this)

Comment: if I remember correctly, setting `sessions` as `volatile` [should work as well](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Comment: `volatile` can fix the initialization problem too, but it doesn't guarantee the proper behavior of the ArrayList itself. Furthermore, using both volatile and synchronized may cause performance problems (not totally sure about that)

Comment: I'm still getting a NullPointer on the initialization even after making it `volatile`

Comment: see the other answer - maybe it is about separate `this` instances

Comment: @erosb what do you mean by "does not guarantee the proper behavior of the ArrayList itself"? Do you mean the support of concurrent operations?

Comment: yes, I mean that declaring the reference volatile won't make the instance itself thread-safe, so the synchronized block is still needed for reading and writing the list